# Facing issue while executing OSGi bundle it throws “/hibernate.cfg.xml not found”

Tags: java, hibernate, osgi-bundle

Facing issue “/hibernate.cfg.xml not found” while executing OSGi bundle. 
I have created a OSGi bundle through Apache felix bundle plugin, in my bundle I am  connecting database through hibernate. When I execute my bundle in OSGi container it throws error. I have added all hibernate related xml files (like hibernate.cfg.xml) through resources tag in POM.xml file in the root folder of the bundle.

Error is

***SessionFactory creation failed:org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found***

This may be minor issue but I could not figure it out, please help me to resolve the issue

This is my POM.xml file

……… …….................
..................................................

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>D:\WSNew\HCB-VCDPlugin100\src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <excludeDependencies>*;scope=provided|runtime</excludeDependencies>
                <instructions>
                    <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>
                    <Embed-Directory>OSGI-INF/lib</Embed-Directory>
                    <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
                    <!-- Export-Package>${project.exports}</Export-Package> -->
                    <!--<_exportcontents>${project.exports}</_exportcontents> -->
                    <Import-Package>org.osgi.framework, ,org.apache.log4j,org.hibernate,org.hibernate.cfg,org.hibernate.transform,org.quartz,org.quartz.impl,javax.xml.transform,org.w3c.dom,org.xml.sax,javax.xml.parsers,!*</Import-Package>
                    <Bundle-Activator>com.abclcorp.hcb.vddservice.impl.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
                    <!-- <Private-Package>org.foo.myproject.*</Private-Package> -->
                    <_exportcontents>*</_exportcontents>
                </instructions>
                <archive>
                    <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>resources/configuration</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>CronScheduler.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>resources/log4j</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>log4j.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>     
        <resource>
            <directory>resources/logs</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>CronScheduler.log</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
 <resource>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>                         
    </resources>        
</build>
```

Comment: I don't a see a resource tag to include hibernate.cfg.xml in your pom.xml

Comment: resource tag to include all required xml file is in my pom.xml file but missing in my post now I included that and you can see now. Actually I had posted portion of pom.xml file. Proble is that when I execute bundle it never find xml file required by hibernate, I checked my bundle's contents by unzip it all the xml files are added properly along with source code. I think it is not comes in the class-path of the bundle thats why it not visible to class file. Help me to resolve this issue.